# Long delay on TcpClient for certain package sizes?

Tags: c#, tcp

I've written a very small application to get a feeling for TCP latencies on our local network. That's where I encountered a very strange delay for certain package sizes that I could up to now not relate to a bug of mine.

Using the code below, I get sub-millisecond ping/pong times for all DataLengths up to 100 kiB, with one strange exception: if DataLength is between about 1010 and 2400 bytes, there seems to be a fixed 400ms delay added to that for no reason I can see.

Where does this long delay come from?

Client code

```
using (var client = new TcpClient())
{
    client.Connect(Server);  // Server is set somewhere else

    var stream = client.GetStream();
    var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8) { AutoFlush = true };
    var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);


    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    string data = "".PadLeft(DataLength, 'T');

    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfPings; i++)
    {
        stopwatch.Restart();
        writer.WriteLine(data);
        reader.ReadLine();
        // record elapsed time
    }
}
```

Server code

```
while (true)
{
    var client = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();

    var stream = client.GetStream();
    var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
    var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8) { AutoFlush = true };
    while (client.Connected)
    {
        var request = reader.ReadLine();
        if (request == null)
            break;
        writer.WriteLine(request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This delay seems to be coming from something like [Nagle's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) which is used to collect multiple small packages before sending.

The problem I experienced is described in this [knowledgebase article.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214397/en-us)

`TcpClient` has a `NoDelay` property that, when set to true, avoids this behaviour.